How to determine if all pairs in an array have the same GCD optimally?
I am trying the following competitive programming problem:

G. GCDland Mystical Arrays
time limit per test 1 second
memory limit per test 256 megabytes
In the eccentric town of GCDland, there lives a mathematician named Theo, who has a wild and paranoid conspiracy theory. Theo is convinced that in certain mystical arrays, the greatest common divisor (GCD) of every possible pair of numbers is always the same. He believes that these arrays are messages from an ancient civilization trying to communicate with us through numbers.
Theo's friends think he's gone off the deep end, but he's determined to prove them wrong and uncover the truth behind these arrays. He needs your help to validate his theory. Given an array of integers, your task is to determine whether the GCD of every pair of numbers in the array is indeed the same. If Theo's theory holds true for the given array, you should confirm it; otherwise, you should debunk it.
The GCD of two numbers is the largest positive integer that divides both numbers without leaving a remainder.
Input
The first line contains an integer  (2≤≤100,000), the number of elements in the array.
The second line contains integers (1≤≤10^7), the elements of the array.
Output
Print "YES" if the GCD of every pair of numbers in the array is the same. Otherwise, print "NO".

You can look at the codeforces problem here.
This is my code:
int gcd(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0)
        return a;
    return gcd(b, a % b);
}


int solve()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> v;


    int first, second;
    cin >> first >> second;
    v.push_back(first);
    v.push_back(second);

    const int x = gcd(v[0], v[1]);

    for (int i = 2; i < n; i ++)
    {
        int newval;
        cin >> newval;
        v.push_back(newval);
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            //cout << "Starting gcd(" <<v[i]<< "," <<v[j]<<")"<< endl;
            if (x != gcd(v[i], v[j]))
            {
                cout << "NO\n";
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "YES\n";
    return 0;
}

It fails because of time limit, so I tried optimizing the gcd() function with memoization to the following function:
int gcd(int a, int b,  map<pair<int,int>, int> &hashmap) {

    if (b == 0)
    {
        return a;
    }

    pair<int,int> key = make_pair(a,b);
    auto it = hashmap.find(key);

    if (it != hashmap.end())
    {
        return it->second;
    }
    else
    {
        int result = gcd(b, a % b, hashmap);
        hashmap.emplace(key, result);
        return result;
    }
}

And it made it faster on certain test cases, but it still fails overall. I don't have access to a coach and really don't know what to do. I also thought that there must be a better way of comparing each pair, but had no success.

Your problem is the quadratic runtime, of the comparison. Try to loot at the problem given to you on a piece of paper first.

This has little to do with C++ specifically, but everything with algorithms. Just in case, as a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

(2≤≤100,000) -- Your double-nested for loop will iterate 10,000,000,000 times.  So there is little chance your code will pass any speed tests.  One thing you should know about "competitive programming" sites -- the questions there are designed so that there will always be a naive, simple, "solution" that is easily written up, but the issue is that those solutions will never work when the data is large.  The goal of these questions is to see if you can come up with the algorithm, data structure(s), or math "trick" to solve the problem.

Also, C++ has std::gcd.  There was no need to write your own.  In all likelihood, std::gcd would have been more optimal than your version, which uses recursion thus has to set up the call stack on each iteration.

A candidate NlogN FFT style solution would be to compute x[i] = gcd(x[2*i], x[2*i+1]) and step through the array i+=2 Halve the length, rinse and repeat. There may be other go faster tricks possible.

@MartinBrown: That doesn't actually work - for example, it fails on input [2, 6, 2, 6].

@user2357112 Fair point. I should have added that gcd cannot be larger than the smallest non-zero element in the array. Starting from that initial guess and refining it by guess=gcd(guess, x[i]) against the given array might be a linear time solution.

@MartinBrown: Doesn't work either. Try that with [1, 2, 2], and it'll start with a guess of 1 and stay with that guess the whole time, even though gcd(2, 2) = 2.

Since we want to check for all pairs of numbers having the same GCD, we can assume the GCD of any pair of numbers is this common GCD and then verify that assumption. It is simple to take the GCD of the first two numbers (which are guaranteed to exist since N is at least 2).
Then, if any element of the array is not divisible by this GCD, the answer is "NO". After this check, we can divide every element by the presumed GCD and inspect the factors of this quotient. If more than one element has the same prime factor, then the answer is also "NO" since the GCD of at least two elements would be larger than the presumed GCD by at least a factor of that prime.
Sample implementation:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
int main() {
    int N;
    std::cin >> N;
    std::vector<int> vals(N);
    for (int& x : vals) std::cin >> x;
    int gcd = std::gcd(vals[0], vals[1]);
    std::vector<bool> seenFactor(1e7 + 1);
    for (int x : vals) {
        if (x % gcd) {
            std::cout << "NO\n";
            return 0;
        }
        x /= gcd;
        for (int d = 2; d * d <= x; ++d) {
            if (x % d == 0) {
                if (seenFactor[d]) {
                    std::cout << "NO\n";
                    return 0;
                }
                seenFactor[d] = true;
                while (x % d == 0) x /= d;
            }
        }
        if (x > 1) {
            if (seenFactor[x]) {
                std::cout << "NO\n";
                return 0;
            }
            seenFactor[x] = true;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "YES\n";
}


One usual optimization strategy is to avoid doing things you don't need. In your case, you determine the GCD of every pair, just to find out whether they all have the same GCD. However, it just requires a single pair with a different GCD to get a result.
The different way to look at this problem is to look at a number as a product of its prime factors. E.g. 105=3×5×7, 28=2×2×7. These prime factors can occur more than once and there is only one set of prime factors for every number. The GCD is also made up of the prime factors. The GCD of 105 and 28 is 7, which is simply the overlap of the sets {3,5,7} and {2,2,7}.
Concerning the implementation, if you're limited to small (as in 32 bit) numbers, the set of prime numbers they can represent is limited, so having a hard-coded list of these primes is possible and probably worthwhile. You can go through these primes and verify whether each of the inputs has this as prime factor. If all numbers have that prime factor, it is part of the GCD. If a prime factor appears in exactly zero or one number, that is fine, too. Note that a prime factor can appear more than once in the same number. Also, it can appear both in the GCD and in the non-GCD factors of a number.
Notes:

For most part of that implementation, you can ignore how often a prime factor occurs, so you can use a single bit to represent whether it is present or not. This allows using efficient bitwise operations.
You can determine a suspected GCD from the first two numbers. All other numbers can then first be divided by that to see if it is a common factor at all. The result can then be scanned for prime factors. This can easily reduce the range of primes that you even have to check for.

